# What's the best language to write Selenium Tests?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, automated-tests

I'm thinking of using Selenium IDE for automate testing of a web app.

My question is what is the weight of selecting a programming language for test case writing?

I'm not worried about nitty-gritties of languages themselves, but more concerned about how easy it's to maintain a large test collection (i.e it looks as if C# uses NUnit for test suit creation, while python uses code to do that).

And how it affects the portability of tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintaining a large test suite will have a degree of effort, regardless of what language you use to create your tests. As a personal preference, I would go with Ruby / Cucumber  framework.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium WebDriver is mostly meant to be used with Java or at least C#. However, there are tons of examples for that stacks